# Automorphism group of the Galois Group

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

If we let $F \subseteq K$ be an extension of fields and $G = \text{Gal}(K/F)$, is there anything interesting to be said about $\text{Aut}(G)$, the group of automorphisms of $G$ (not of $K$ over $F$) as it pertains to $F$ and $K$? I realize this is quite broad, but I suppose that I am curious as to whether the automorphisms of the Galois group can be interpreted in a natural way in the context of the underlying field(s) and vice versa.

Comment: This is far from being an answer but you might want to ask first if $Int(G)$ has a nice interpretation in the context of the underlying field(s). If $Aut(G)$ has a nice interpretation, it is likely that $Int(G)$ has too.

Comment: @ClémentGuérin What do you mean $Int(G)$? I've never encountered that notation before.

Comment: Sorry, it is also denoted $Inn(G)$ the subgroup of inner automorphisms.

Comment: @ClémentGuérin Okay, I suspected that is what you meant. I'll give that a look.